# Deploying Flask Application to Azure App Servce (Linux)

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I was deploying a flask applications to Azure App Services with the following (example) file structure.

```
flask-app
├── application.py
└── web
    └── __init__.py
```

Inside `__init__.py` I declared `app = Flask(__name__)` (and of course do other things such as setup the configuration and add the controllers). Then, inside `application.py`, I just did `from web import app`.

When attempting to deploying this to Azure App Services, I would receive the following error when App Services would try to start the application: **"Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'application'"**.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, I modified `application.py` to do the following:

```py
from web import app
app = app
```

And then the app was able to be deployed. Of course, I'm somewhat skeptical that this is a proper fix or if what was happening was a bug, but I thought I would share this in case it helped others in the future.